# How to draw a smooth path on the map, based on GPS coordinates?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, maps, gis

I made an app which tracks your movement and draws a line on the map. The coordinate is recorded every 5 seconds. As expected, the phone's GPS is sometimes off and I get sudden "jumps" of 500 meters to another area, and then it jumps back. If I connect the dots this way I'll get a very ugly line.

Could you point me to some algorithms or libraries which help filter out these dots and help make the line more realistic?

What I can think of is iterate through the points, calculate the distance, and if the distance is greater than 10 meters then discard the point. That's probably not good enough though and what I should do is keep the point but move it closer to the previous point. I would not like to discover hot water again so I'm interested in existing algorithms.

Comment: google **sliding average** ...

Comment: I would go for sliding median (that would eleminate outliers). Or you could try to detect outliers by calculating the distance to the last position and calculate if the data is possible based on the max speed you can perform.

Comment: You might have a look at the [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm).

Comment: do you have timestamps with GPS coordinates? Are there any assumptions on movement patterns to make (e.g. it is a human walking or a helicopter)? Even Kalman filter might be sufficient with a good set of assumptions

Comment: I tried the Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm yesterday but unfortunately it didn't make a substantial improvement.

For example, here's a map I have, the blue is what I have based on the GPS coordinates and the red is the actual movement:
https://imgur.com/dlPIdC2

I'm not saying that it should try and snap the route to the streets, that would be too complicated. But I would like to cut off the weird branches which obviously don't make sense.

The GPS location also provides an "accuracy" value, maybe I should try and incorporate it somehow.

We are assuming the person is walking.